# Hide folder that user uses currently

Tags: permissions, ftp, acl, file-sharing, file-server

I'm searching for a ftp server or any idea to achieve hiding folder from others when somebody is working in it.

For example:
I have 3 folders: A B C when I working in A, anybody who is also connected to the server can't see it or work with it.

I need this to avoid overriding.

Comment: What type of files are in the directory? If it's code then version control would be the much better option.

Comment: Each folder contains database program and database, in databases are invoices. Each folder is other company